# DatePicker in MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

i am using `@Html.JQueryUI().DatepickerFor` helper method in my mvc4 application. It is showing the calender correctly at first time but it is not showing once the form is posted. Can anyone tell me what i am missing in it?

Comment: I am using http post.just example: @using (Html.BeginForm())
{}in mvc

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are using AJAX to submit the form and in case of successful submission you are refreshing the contents and thus the date picker is no longer bound to the input field. So inside the success callback of your AJAX request you need to rebind it:

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#some_id').html(data);
    $('#id_of_your_input_element').datepicker();
}
```

Or if you are using an Ajax.BeginForm you could subscribe to the Success event in the AjaxOptions:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { Success = "success", UpdateTargetId = "someId" }))
{
    ...
}
```

and then write the `success` callback:

```
function success(data) {
    $('#id_of_your_input_element').datepicker();
}
```

Comment: Hii thanks for your responsei m not using ajax post rather using the following code:@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
   
   @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}   
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">         
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StartDate)     
            @Html.JQueryUI().DatepickerFor(m => m.StartDate)
        </li>
    
}

Comment: And what is the controller action to which you submit the form doing? Is it rendering the same view again? If you don't use AJAX there's no reason why reloading the page would prevent the date picker from working, especially if it worked the first time when the form was rendered.

Comment: yes it is rendering the same view.The controller action method is [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult VisitorDisplay(Visitor oVisitor)
        {
            //need to save details
            
            return View("VisitorDisplay",oVisitor);
        }

Comment: So far I don't see anything wrong with your code. Are there some javascript errors in the console?