# DatePicker in View in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I am using ASPX.NET MVC4, with aspx as view engine. I have a function at my controller, which takes as input a start date and an enddate. I want these dates to be given by the user using a DatePicker, or something similar, and after that to be passed at the controller.

However, I found that asp does not have a DatePicker. How do I use a datepicker for my application?

I also looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212031/datepicker-in-mvc4) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639673/custom-datepicker-html-helper-for-mvc4-using-razor-view) but I did not find them really helpful. Do you know how I am able to do that?

Comment: There are *tons* of date picker plugins/elements/etc. out there.  jQuery is generally included in ASP.NET MVC templates by default, so the jQuery UI Datepicker seems like a simple and straightforward solution: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Hi @David. I have also the same problem. I copied exactly the same code at my code, but I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'" Do you know what I have done wrong?

Comment: @JimBlum: That error means the jQuery UI library hasn't been loaded (or at least isn't loaded before the method is invoked).  Check that you're referencing it correctly and use a browser debugging tool (FireBug, Chrome tools, etc.) to check if it's being successfully retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a standard ASP.NET MVC template then you're *very likely* already loading/using jQuery.  It's also *pretty likely* that you're loading/using [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/).  (If not, it's [easy enough to include](http://jqueryui.com/download/).  There's even [a handy NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery.ui.combined/) for it.)

Given this, converting any `input type="text"` (or `@Html.TextBox()` or any number of other server-side helpers which emit an `input type="text"`) into a "date picker" is a single line of code:

```
$(targetInputs).datepicker();
```